# 'No component definition' warning for LWC even though I defined the component on VF page (Lightning Out)

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-out

I am using Lightning out to display LWC on VF page. I have included the definition of LWC on the VF page. Even then, my LWC loads very slowly on the VF page and I get the following warning in the console of my browser:
[image]

I did all the steps as per [this salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.lightning_out_dependencies) but I am still getting the warning. It has slowed the loading of my LWC and I am not able to find the reason why. Please help. Thank You.

**VF page Code:**

```js
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" controller="ControllerCustomReportPreview"  tabStyle="Account" >

    <style>
        .headerRow .TableTitle {
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="customReportPreviewLWC" /> 

    <script>
        //Use the app
        $Lightning.use("c:customReportApp", function() { 
            //Create the LWC
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:customReportPreviewLWC", {
                //pass parameters if required
            },
            //This name will be used to place LWC                           
            "customReportPreviewLWC",
                function(component) {//call back function
                 console.log("Lightning Web Component  created Successfully!!");
                }
           );
        });
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

**customReportApp.app code:**

```js
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:customReportSelectionLWC"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="c:customReportFilterLWC"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="c:customReportSortingLWC"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="c:customReportPreviewLWC"/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the dependencies that you don't need?

Comment: @SanderdeJong Yes. I kept only one dependency that I need. Even then I am getting the same warning.

Comment: The fact that it complains about the missing dependency and that the LWC loads slowly, but it does load, suggests that customReportApp.app is not deployed (properly). If you open Developer Console, then File > Open Lightning Resources. Can you find customReportApp.app in the list?

Comment: @SanderdeJong Yes, I can find it in the list. I am able to open it.

Comment: can you try extending ltng:outAppUnstyled class. Also, try adding the component using the same way that we used to call component inside another component like  <c:customReportSelectionLWC />

Comment: Looks like a similar issue has been reported with lightning aura component (check this: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001FTDpQAO). Can you check whether `Enabling CDN for Lightning component framework` resolves your issue? Ref: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_lc_cdn.htm

Comment: @arut `Enabling CDN for Lightning component framework` did not work. I am still getting the warning.

Comment: @AmitSingh extending `ltng:outAppUnstyled` class did not work. But your suggestion to add the component as `<c:customReportSelectionLWC />` instead of `<aura:dependency resource="c:customReportSelectionLWC"/>` worked! I am not getting the warning anymore. Thank You. How was it not mentioned in the official documentation?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.lightning_out_dependencies), the following is mentioned:

> A standalone Aura dependency app is used only to specify the
> dependencies for Lightning Out.
>
> This standalone Aura dependency app uses the myAppComponent Lightning
> web component in the default c namespace.
>
> ```
> <aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
>     <aura:dependency resource="c:myAppComponent"/> 
> </aura:application>
> ```

In the warning message too, it is suggested to use `<aura:dependency resource="c:myAppComponent"/>`. Turns out that it does not work. The warning persists.

In the same documentation, there is a Note below that says the following:

> NOTE To reference a Lightning web component in an Aura app or an Aura component, use the naming convention `<namespace:camelCaseComponentName>`.

When we use `<namespace:camelCaseComponentName>`, the warning disappears. The documentation gives the impression that both methods will work but it is `<namespace:camelCaseComponentName>` (which is mentioned in the Note) that actually works.